# Prevent skype highlighting from corrupting textareas

Tags: html, textarea, skype

In short, a text area programatically populated with a phone number in it, with the Skype plugin installed, produces the highlighting tags.

Thus,

```
(418) 555-1234
```

becomes

```
begin_of_the_skype_highlighting (418) 555-1234 end_of_the_skype_highlighting
```

And if *that* string is put inside the textarea, the Skype highlighting will encapsulate it *again*, *Ad infinitum*.

How do you prevent that?

Comment: uninstall Skype plugin is not an option? I always hated that it converted regular numbers to links.

Comment: @moontear: I wish it was, but I can't prevent people from installing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have a look at http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=96959&st=0

Looks like it is a reported bug, but not solved until now.

Suggestions are to use a meta tag (*which seems to **not** work across all Skype plugins*)

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```

Introduce a non visible character that will break the skype algorithm for identifying phones

```
+123 456<span style="display:none;">_</span> 789
```

(*don't think this can work with textareas though*)

And of course disable the plugin, if the issue is with your own access to that page.

---

**Update**

Check if any of the two examples in http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/Qy7uw/ work. (*i do not have skype to check*)

I am using the zero-width-joiner **`&zwj;`** and the familiar **`&nbsp;`**

Comment: Stupid Skype. This is so annoying - it should follow some standard to identify phone numbers (Like `tel:xxxx`) and leave the rest of the content well alone (Would +1 but out of votes)

Comment: You're right with the textarea, can't put a span in there. But for the meta tag, it actually does the opposite, it enables highlighting (for future Skype plugins once they get there), not prevent it, correct?

Comment: @MPelletier, look at http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=78380 and http://skype.otherlinks.co.uk/page.asp?id=toolbar_number_formatting According to that, only numbers that are wrapped in comment tags (*with specific rules*) will be highlighted `<!-- sphoneid --><!-- sphoneid -->`.

Comment: I thank you for your time. Apparently the latest toolbars stay clear of textareas and don't mess them up anymore. Something else I discovered in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS only, it can be removed by overriding the styles used by Skype. Try adding these two lines to your stylesheet:

```
span.skype_pnh_container {display:none !important;}
span.skype_pnh_print_container {display:inline !important;}
```

**edit** Skype have started to add unique numbers to the classes, you can solve it using the new Css 3 selector:

```
span.skype_pnh_container {display:none !important;}
span.skype_pnh_print_container, span[class^="skype_pnh_print_container"] {display:inline !important;}
```

Comment: Removing it using styles is no longer an option as they generate a random salt to the container class like skype_pnh_container_12345

Comment: @Timo: I believe Eduardo's update (CSS3) should handle that (the latter rule matches classes styles starting with `skype_pnh_print_container`), did you try it?

Comment: yes, I seem to have missed it weirdly enough, too bad there is no CSS2 solution. I used the SKYPE_TOOLBAR meta tag to solve it. I actually saw your first solution mentioned on some post by Paul Irish on some webpage, seems it's outdated now.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly hack, not tried yet, but the text that goes in the textarea could be generated with an unprintable character between each printable character. Might damage special encoding though...