# Replacing string in c# to block skype phone formatting

Tags: c#, string, skype

I have two strings:

```
 string ThePhone = "XXX-XXX-XXXX"
 string SkypeBlock = "-<span style='display:none;'>-</span>";
```

I want to replace *the last dash (-)* in **ThePhone** with **SkypeBlock**

And the desired result:

```
TheNewPhone = "XXX-XXX-<span style='display:none;'>-</span>XXXX"
```

How?

Comment: You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269220/prevent-skype-highlighting-from-corrupting-textareas

Comment: It's the quotations that are causing me the problem.

Comment: You guys are downvoting an answer that'll help a lot of people who need to block the skype phone reformatting. Whatever.

Comment: Because your question make them confusing, I've edited it, But, need some reviewing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should do the trick:

```
string ThePhone = "XXX-XXX-XXXX";
string SkypeBlock = "-<span style=\"display:none;\">-</span>";

ThePhone = ThePhone.Substring(0, 8) + SkypeBlock + ThePhone.Substring(8, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution

```
var ThePhone = "XXX-XXX-XXXX";
var SkypeBlock = "<span style='display:none;'>-</span>";
var lastDash = ThePhone.LastIndexOf('-'); // Find position of the last dash
var theNewPhone = thePhone.Remove(lastDash, 1).Insert(lastDash, SkypeBlock); // Replace last dash
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. However, I'm still struggling with the quotations; the line is underlined red.

Comment: Ok, I got it with the @ symbol. There's still a problem: it truncates the last 4 digits!